# Authorize.Net Network Change

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, payment-gateway, authorize.net, payment-processing

Authorize.Net will be changing from Akamai SureRoute as the CDN to CloudFlare. Here is the [announcement](https://support.authorize.net/s/article/Authorize-Net-Network-Change-FAQ).

The article mentions:

> Phase 2 (October 15, 2019 ~10:00am PT) – We will automatically be directing all Sandbox api sites/traffic directly to our network.
>
> **Needed Action**: Ensure certificate is installed/trusted by
>   host/solution, Entrust L1 K certificate. Please consult with your
>   developer/solution provider. If certificate is needed please see
>   support article: [How do I obtain Authorize.Net Certificate for my
>   host/solution provider?](https://support.authorize.net/s/article/How-do-I-obtain-Authorize-Nets-SSL-Certificate-for-my-host-solution-provider)

The above [link](https://support.authorize.net/s/article/How-do-I-obtain-Authorize-Nets-SSL-Certificate-for-my-host-solution-provider) to obtain the Authorize.Net certificate points to [Entrust.Net](https://support.authorize.net/s/article/How-do-I-obtain-Authorize-Nets-SSL-Certificate-for-my-host-solution-provider), which lists various options to purchase the certificates.

We provide Authorize.Net integration using the [dotnet sdk](https://github.com/AuthorizeNet/sdk-dotnet). Which I installed as a Nuget package.

How do I find out if we do need a certificate? If we do, do I have to purchase it from Entrust?

Comment: We are also confussed about this change.

I have contacted the developer@authorize.net .But i got the reply to ensure the L1k certificate.

But i couldn't find a way to ensure this in my Ubuntu server.If you got any update regarding this can you please post that in the same thread.

Answer (score 0):

I have gone through the link provided by authorize.net(https://support.authorize.net/s/article/Authorize-Net-Network-Change-FAQ) and i checked my code for the API endpoints specified in the link content.

We are using the Akamai end point for the transaction in production(PHP SDK for Authorize.net).
I have used the Akamai endpoint  https://api2.authorize.net/xml/v1/request.api  in my code for production.

As of my understanding If you are using Non Akamai API endpoint you don't have to change anything in the code or in server.

Please check your code and find the Endpoints used for transaction.It will help you to identify the actions you have to do before the network change.

Reference :-  https://support.authorize.net/s/article/Authorize-Net-Network-Change-FAQ

> What about URLs not on Akamai? The API endpoints not on Akamai will
>   not be changing or impact and will continue to function as they do
>   today.    Needed Action: No actions or changes.        Production API Urls:
>   https://api.authorize.net/xml/v1/request.api
>   https://api.authorize.net/soap/v1/Service.asmx
>   https://secure.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll

Latest Discussion in authorize.net community forum :-

https://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/Integration-and-Testing/Confused-About-Certificate-Requirements-On-Network-Change/m-p/69610